# Which packages for OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, development

sorry for the simple question:
Which packages do I need to install to get OpenGL working (including building a program which uses OpenGL)?

(I use Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. There is no such package as opengl, openGL or mesa.)

Comment: It depends on the specific hardware in use, and more often then not, there is no need to install anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that for 20.04 the development package (required for building a program which uses OpenGL) is `libgl-dev`:

```
$ apt show libgl-dev
Package: libgl-dev
Version: 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1
Priority: optional
Section: libs
Source: libglvnd
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian X Strike Force <debian-x@lists.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 1389 kB
Depends: libgl1 (= 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1), libglx-dev
Breaks: libgl1-mesa-dev (<< 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04), libglvnd-dev (<< 1.3.0-1), mesa-common-dev (<< 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04)
Replaces: libgl1-mesa-dev (<< 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04), libglvnd-dev (<< 1.3.0-1), mesa-common-dev (<< 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04)
Homepage: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/glvnd/libglvnd
Download-Size: 97.8 kB
APT-Sources: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
Description: Vendor neutral GL dispatch library -- GL development files
 This is an implementation of the vendor-neutral dispatch layer for
 arbitrating OpenGL API calls between multiple vendors on a per-screen basis.
 .
 This package provides the development environment for compiling programs
 against the GL library.
```

Previous versions used the Mesa implementation explicitly, i.e. `libgl1-mesa-dev`.